# Key Value Pair Datatype in FB 4.6

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashbuilder4

I have a JSON response form HTTP request.

```
"AdditionalData": {
    "default" : "checked",
    "example" : "empty"
 }
```

This specific response would ideally be interoperated as a dictionary type (Key value pair). But when I auto-detect the return type of the JSON, FB 4.6 makes it of type Object. This does not work for me. For some reason the AdditionalData object in the model that I'm mapping is always null. What data type can I manually set this response to?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can force the result of a complex grouping to be anything but an Object when it gets returned. Once it arrives you could convert it into an ArrayCollection (of Objects or other ArrayCollections) though.

Comment: ArrayCollection would only be acceptable if the format was something like `"AdditionalData":{["default":"checked","example":"empty"]}` unfortunately. I tried, but thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to convert it?

Comment: It needs to map to an object.. I cant change the response data. Need to deal with it as it is.